Rsbuild Dev Server & Production Build Memory usage exceeds limit despite setting NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size
I'm encountering high memory usage with the Rsbuild dev server and cannot effectively limit it, despite setting the NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size environment variable as recommended in the Rsbuild documentation.
However, monitoring memory usage via the Activity Monitor shows it consistently exceeds 5 GB, regardless of these settings.
Relevant Tech Stack:
node: v18.17.0
yarn: v1.22.22
react: v18.2
@rsbuild/core: v1.1.10
typeScript: v4.9.4
Device Specs:
OS: macOS Sequoia (v15.0)
RAM: 16 GB
I’ve attempted to restrict memory consumption using the following methods:
Using Node,
"script":{
"build": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/@rsbuild/core/bin/rsbuild.js build"
} 

Using NODE_OPTIONS,
"script":{
"build": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 rsbuild build"
}

Setting the environment variable in rsbuild.config.js file,
process.env.NODE_OPTIONS = '--max-old-space-size=4096'

